# CSS Transition don't work (height and margin)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, transition

I really don't know why this doesn't work: [fiddle](http://goo.gl/zk35Q8) 
When I click on the red box, I want it to move down 50px and change the height to 200px.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this instead:

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/Yu5LM/)

```
$('#box').click(function(){
  $(this).css('margin-top','50px');
  $(this).css('height','200px');
});
```

I also added in the `-webkit-`/`-moz-` vendors/prefixes.

Comment: Is it just me, or is the transition for margin-top not working this way?

Answer (score 3):

Well this is how CSS work sadly, IDs take higher priority as a selector than a class would read this [article](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/30797-css-priority-rules-weight) for more info.

On click i added a class with the size/marign changes you wanted.

```
.box {
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    display: block;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.box-active {
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

The JS

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("box-active");
});
```

Here's a fiddle with the working solution.
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sLLAY/3/)

Comment: Man, that's a cool solution!
But the solution from JohnC worked also fine and is a bit cleaner, but thanks!

Comment: Anytime I'm glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
  function changeprop(id)
{
    $(id).css({'margin-top', '50px'});
    $(id).css({'height', '200px'});
}
```

SyntaxError: missing : after property id
$(id).css({'margin-top', '50px'});

use : between property name and value not ,

```
  function changeprop(id)
{
    $(id).css({'margin-top': '50px'});
    $(id).css({'height': '200px'});
}
```

this will work fine

maybe you can write your code in local html file and watch the console message throw firebug or other develop tool

thus can suffer less from error